# AWS DeviceFarm support for automotive systems

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to know whether AWS DeviceFarm support for automotive systems.AWS Device Farm documentation I didn’t get any info about support for automative systems.please anyone know do help me in this thread.

Thank you in advanc